# how to assign a multidimensional array to a structure?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, struct

I am new to c++ and for my program I want to assign a 2d array pointer to structure. Code is

```
struct normal
{
    double n_x, n_y;
};
```

This is the structure I defined and I want to assign a 2d array pointer in main like this:

```
normal **normal_cell;
*normal_cell = new normal[p];
for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
{
    normal_cell[i] = new normal[4];
}
```

and this 2d pointer should be passed to a function. When I try to do this my program is not running. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `normal_cell = new normal*[p]` instead of `*normal_cell = new normal[p]`

Comment: I have tried to compile but I got
 error: ‘p’ was not declared in this scope
 normal_cell = new normal*[p];

Comment: then define p, e.g. `int p = 10;` before assigning normal_cell

Answer (score 2):

In C++, we use vectors instead of arrays and pointers:

```
#include<vector>
using std:: vector;
struct normal
{
    double n_x, n_y;
};

vector<vector<normal>> normal_cell;
void foo() {
    int p=10;
    normal_cell.resize(p);
    for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        normal_cell.at(i).resize(4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try it:

```
    //if normal_cell[4][5]
    const int m = 4; //row
    const int n = 5; //column
    normal **normal_cell = new normal*[m]; //new row
    for(int i=0; i<m; ++i)
        normal_cell[i] = new normal[n]; //new column
```